# Angular 6 - Instagram POST API for authentication in Angular shows CORS error

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, angular6, instagram

I've searched over various sites about resolving CORS error but not found any working solution.
So, in one of my project, I've Instagram authentication enabled. I get the ?code=XXX when calling first get URL as per [doc](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) when calling `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`.

For the next step, I've to call a POST method to get IG auth-token and user details. `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` with required data. But calling this API shows me CORS error:

[image: IG CORS error]

My Code(using Angular HTTPClient Module):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IgauthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  instagramGetToken (igcode) {
    let data = {
      client_id: 'XXX',
      client_secret: 'XXX',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
      code: igcode
    }
    try {
      return this.http.post('http://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', data, httpOptions);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return err;
    };
  }
}
```

**Note:** This works fine in Postman

Comment: Did you add your origin, where you registered your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know what was happening, but, instead of sending data as JSON, it requires to POST data as Form Data. So, I did this:

```
const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('client_id', 'XXX')
    .set('client_secret', 'XXX')
    .set('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
    .set('redirect_uri', `${location.protocol}//${location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '')}/`)
    .set('code', igcode)

    return this.http.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
    body.toString(),
    {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    }
    );
```

And this worked well. Still curious why it didn't work with JSON data.